# How to update classes

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

```py
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def number_update(self):
        self.number += 1


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

class1 = Dog(1)
class2 = Cat(class1.number * 0.5)

class1.number_update()
print(class1.number)
print(class2.number)
```

Current output: **2, 0.5**

I want: **2, 1**

I really simplified it, so I hope you will understand

Thank you for help

Comment: Mandatory link to Ned Batchelder: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Do you want to be able to call `class1.number_update()` repeatedly and have `class2.number` follow the value of `class1.number`?

Comment: Terminology note: these aren't *classes*, they are *instances of classes*. So `class1` and `class2` are not class objects, they are instances of `Dog` and `Cat` classes, which are the class objects.

Comment: Fundamentally, Python `int` objects are immutable. So you'd have to wrap your `int` in some class, say `class Value` which exposes mutator methods and then pass the *same `Value` object* to both instances of your class. This to me is fundamentally a bad design, though. But that's how you could do it.

Answer (score 0):

You are running `class1.number_update()` after you define the `class2` variable, so the `class1` variable has a value of 1 when you define `class2`, and after you define `class2`, `class1` becomes into 2. To fix this, just switch around those two lines:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def number_update(self):
        self.number += 1


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

class1 = Dog(1)
class1.number_update()

class2 = Cat(class1.number * 0.5)
print(class1.number)
print(class2.number)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could return the number in `number_update()`:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

    def number_update(self):
        self.number += 1
        return self.number


class Cat(object):
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = number

class1 = Dog(1)
class2 = Cat(class1.number_update() * .5)

print(class1.number)
print(class2.number)
```

Output:

```
2
1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through the lines of your main function and trace the values of `Dog` and `Cat`

```
class1 = Dog(1)  # Dog=1; Cat=undefined
class2 = Cat(class1.number * 0.5)  # Dog=1; Cat=1*0.5=0.5

class1.number_update()  # Dog=2; Cat=0.5
print(class1.number)  # >>>"2"
print(class2.number)  # >>>"0.5"
```

Your class doesn't have a reference to Dog's `number` member, it just *references* the `Cat` class property.

EDIT: It doesn't copy, it creates a reference directly to the object.

Comment: No, it doesn't shallow copy. It doesn't *copy at all*. In this case, you pass an entirely new object, created by `class1.number*0.5`. But even if you just passed `class1.number`, there would be no shallow copy, it is the same exact object

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, to do this exactly as you want, you'll have to write your own expression and number classes, such as this:

```
class Op:
    def __init__(self, op):
        self.op = op

    def __call__(self, a, b):
        if self.op == "*":
            return a * b
        if self.op == "/":
            return a / b
        if self.op == "-":
            return a - b
        if self.op == "+":
            return a + b

        raise TypeError(f"Unknown op {repr(self.op)}")

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.op

mul = Op("*")
div = Op("/")
add = Op("+")
sub = Op("-")

class Expr:
    def __init__(self, a, b, op):
        self.op = op
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def eval(self):
        return self.op(self.a.eval(), self.b.eval())

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"({self.a} {self.op} {self.b})"

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            b = Number(other)
        else:
            b = other
        a = self
        return Expr(a, b, mul)

    def __div__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            b = Number(other)
        else:
            b = other
        a = self
        return Expr(a, b, div)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            b = Number(other)
        else:
            b = other
        a = self
        return Expr(a, b, add)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            b = Number(other)
        else:
            b = other
        a = self
        return Expr(a, b, sub)

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__mul__(other, self)
    def __rdiv__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__div__(other, self)
    def __rsub__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__sub__(other, self)
    def __radd__(self, other):
        return self.__class__.__add__(other, self)

class Number(Expr):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    def get(self):
        return self._value

    def set(self, new):
        self._value = new

    def increment(self):
        self._value += 1

    def eval(self):
        return self._value

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self._value)

class Dog:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self.number = Number(number)

    def number_update(self):
        self.number.increment()

class Cat:
    def __init__(self, number):
        self._number = number

    @property
    def number(self):
        return self._number.eval()

    @number.setter
    def number(self, new):
        if isinstance(new, (int, float)):
            new = Number(new)

        self._number = new

cls1 = Dog(1)
cls2 = Cat(cls1.number * 0.5)

cls1.number_update()

print(cls1.number)
print(cls2.number)
```

Here, we get the expected output of

```
2
1.0
```